# how to populate data in 'closure' table if we have existing hierachy using parent_id in Gedmo doctrine tree extension?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions, gedmo-loggable

I have existing category hierarchy with parent_id column. I have configured Gedmo Tree extension and update schema. I can see 'level' column is added to category table and category_closure table is created.

How do I populate the data in category_closure table. There are no

```
$repo->verify();
$repo->recover();
```

methods for ClosureTreeRepository. I have tried updating category records so that to trigger TreeListener but still there is no data in category_closure.

How do I populate hierarchy in category_closure table ?

Answer (score 0):

Methods verify and recover are available in `3.0.x-dev` version.

<strike>You are [supposed](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1430) to populate closure data on your own.</strike>